# Where is the jungle temple?

Tags: terraria-console

I can't find the jungle temple, and I've explored the whole jungle I'm not sure how big it is, or if it's not there, please help

Comment: You're looking in the Underground Jungle, not on the surface, right?

Comment: Yes I am. All the way to the underworld

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is (probably) not a bug. It also happened to me once already - the Jungle Temple is NOT necessarily connected to any cave that is also connected to the surface.

This means that you would need to start digging around and hoping to find it eventually. The best way to go about that would be grabbing a few friends and getting them to help you, and remember to always follow caves you dig into.

I would also like to add that you are able to find the temple without killing the wall of flesh, you just have no way of progressing. ([Source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Jungle_Temple), notice that it says "Even before entering Hardmode, Lihzahrds and Flying Snakes can spawn outside the temple, ..." clearly stating that it is there already as killing the Wall of Flesh triggers the Hard Mode)

Comment: Unless they've done some bug fixes, there are ways to get into the Temple before hardmode, much less before the mech bosses. You can use hoiks to pass through the door, or actuators to make the door passable.

Comment: There even is a bug which simply doesn't spawn a few jungle temple blocks resulting in you being able to enter without any fret. I was talking about how you _should_ do it though. I always knew that the Jungle Temple is always there, I only cited a source to give my post some credibility

Answer (score 1):

#### World features are determined based on your version at world generation time

The [Jungle Temple](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Jungle_Temple) wasn't introduced to Console Terraria until the [1.02 Console version update](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Console_Version_history) (equivalent to the 1.2.1.2 PC version). If your world was generated on an earlier version, it won't have a Jungle Temple, even if you later updated your game to the correct version, because features such as the temple and various biomes (e.g. [Snow Biome](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Snow_biome), [Crimson Biome](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Crimson)) are determined when the world is generated. If your world was generated on the base version of the game, you'll need to generate a new world after having updated to get one with a Jungle Temple.

Comment: I actually didn't even consider this, but you are certainly right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your issue isn't what's described in Micheallogg's answer, the "easiest" method to locate the jungle temple is to dig a [hellevator](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Travel#Hellevator) every couple screens, and use weapons that can illuminate caves to hunt outside your site range. A dangersense potion can also be useful as it will illuminate the traps that are all over the Temple. Likewise a Hunter potion can let you identify the Temple by the temple's unique enemies.

The Temple can generate very far down (lower lava layer, even right next to hell), and can also generate in a pocket of jungle disconnected from the main jungle. (I've only seen this happen once though) The underground jungle can also be wider than the surface jungle, especially if corruption or crimson biomes generated next to the surface, so be sure to dig hellevators to the sides of the surface jungle for a few screens too.

Answer (score -2):

To find it you MUST have killed the wall of flesh so you are in hard mode.
Then you will find it underground somewhere. Keep looking

Comment: I'm 90% sure this is dead wrong. If this was the PC version I'd be 100% on that.

Comment: @Fambida You're correct, the temple exists on world generation. Even if it wasn't incorrect, "it's somewhere, keep looking" isn't really a helpful answer anyway.